# What's the most straightforward way to delete emails marked as spam by SpamAssassin?

Tags: perl, email-spam, spam-prevention, spamassassin

I'm on Ubuntu Intrepid, using Postfix and SpamAssassin. I've seen approaches using procmail (like [the one suggested @ Apache](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DeletingAllMailsMarkedSpam)), but I'm looking for a solution that does not use procmail.

This is a programming question because the correct answer will be some form of code that accomplishes the task at hand (my response to the negative votes).

UPDATE to the situation: I used this tutorial and it worked out excellently: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew

Comment: You need to provide some more info.  This could be done at the MUA level if you'd tell us what MUA yo use.  Or once the mails have been delivered to disk,but you don't say if you're using maildir or mbox format.  Depedning on thsoe either a filter in your MUA or grepmail or formail would do.

Comment: If you would say *why* you don't want procmail, it would go a long way towards showing what you *do* want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends at which level you want to delete the spam:

- At the mail client level, using Email client rules (like the ones available in Thunderbird) is easy: just set a rule that delete any email marked as SPAM in the subject.
- At the user level, if mail is received automatically by the machine, you could set some cron job that periodically inspect the local mailbox and again delete mails marked as SPAM.
  It's easy if your local store uses [`maildir`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) since each email is just a file, as opposed to the `mbox` format which would require some more work since it's a single file.
  Setting up `maildir` for postfix is [trivial](http://etc.nkadesign.com/EmailServer/Postfix).
- At the server level, using [`Amavisd`](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/) will allow you to have more control over how mail is handled.
  `Amavisd` has threshold settings where you can define an evasive action depending on the spam score given by spamassassin.
  For instance, anything above 15 points is put in quarantine and anything above 30 points is deleted.
  There are some instructions for [installing Amavisd on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew).

The point is, as far as I know, `spamassassin`'s job is to identify and give spam points to emails. How you want these to be handled is not up to `spamassassin` but the other modules down the chain.